# Retorno função Angularjs / Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

como faço para recuperar o valor desta função usando desta forma:

```
var teste = getUser(); 

function getUser() {
    userService.getUser(userService.getUserLogged().id).success(
        function(res) {
            return res.data;
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

você não vai conseguir retornar um valor de forma syncrona que está disponível em um método assíncrono. neste caso a sua melhor opção, é passar uma função de callback.

Então no lugar de ter algo como:

```
function getUser() {
    userService.getUser(userService.getUserLogged().id).success(
        function(res) {
            return res.data;
        }
    );
}

var usuario = getUser(); 
// fazer algo com o usuario.
```

Você precisa definir uma função de callback como parâmetro do método.

```
function getUser(callback) {
    userService.getUser(userService.getUserLogged().id).success(
        function(res) {
            callback(res.data);
        }
    );
}

getUser(function (usuario) {
    // fazer algo com o usuario.
});
```

Comment: Muito obrigado TobyMosque, me ajudou demais, tinha me esquecido das funções de callback.